# Dream interpretations

Tags: discussion

As I am aware that this site closes questions on dream interpretations, where can people post their questions with regards to dreams. This is a Islamic site and dreams have meanings behind which can be very important in a persons life. If a person has a dream that may have a meaning behind people want to know more information on that dream as there are very limited sources out there.

Putting questions on hold or closing them stops people from gaining personal knowledge, and  before someone refers to me posting this question on the meta site I can't due to myself needing a reputation of 5

Comment: Related (not sure if a duplicate): http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/780

Comment: Related http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14721/how-can-intuitions-be-infallible/14726#14726